# Unable to save csv file with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Sorry for the dummy question but I read lots of topics but my code still do not create and save a .csv file.

```
import pandas as pd
def save_csv(lista):
    try:
        print("Salvando...")
        name_path = time.strftime('%d%m%y') + '01' + '.csv'
        df = pd.DataFrame(lista, columns=["column"])
        df.to_csv(name_path, index=False)
    except:
        pass

dados = [-0.9143399074673653, -1.0944355744868517, -1.1022400576621294]
save_csv(dados)
```

Path name is 'DayMonthYear01.csv' (20121701.csv).

When I run the code it finishes but no file is saved.

The output of the code is just:

```
>>>
RESTART: C:\Users\eduhz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\testeCSV.py
Salvando...
>>>
```

Does anyone knows what am I missing?

Comment: Change the line `except:` with `except Exception as e` and then instead of `pass`, replace it with `print(e)`. That will tell you why you're not saving the data properly. You can't just `pass` without knowing what exception is being thrown.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. The exception is the follows:

[Errno 13] Permission denied: '20121701.csv'

Comment: Looks like you don't have permission to write in that folder. Save the file somewhere else like in `Documents` or `Desktop`. You can also open `IDLE` as Administrator and that should help.

Comment: I was running the script on "Notepad++". Using the IDLE (Python 3.6 32-bit) it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as answered by @Abdou I changed the code to provide me what was the error.

```
import pandas as pd
import time
def save_csv(lista):
    try:
        print("Salvando...")
        name_path = time.strftime('%d%m%y') + '01' + '.csv'
        df = pd.DataFrame(lista, columns=["column"])
        df.to_csv(name_path, index=False)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
dados = [-0.9143399074673653, -1.0944355744868517, -1.1022400576621294]
save_csv(dados)
```

Then I found out it was due to a permission error

> [Errno 13] Permission denied:

caused by the fact Notepad (without being opened as Administrator) does not have access to some directories and therefore anything run inside it wouldn't be able to write to those directories.

I tried running Notepad as administrator but it didn't work.

The solution was running the code with the Python IDLE.

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the time module? All i did was add that and it made a 21121701.csv with the 3 entries in one columns in the current working directory.

```
import pandas as pd
import time

def save_csv(lista):
        print("Salvando...")
        name_path = time.strftime('%d%m%y') + '01' + '.csv'
        df = pd.DataFrame(lista, columns=["column"])
        df.to_csv(name_path, index=False)

dados = [-0.9143399074673653, -1.0944355744868517, -1.1022400576621294]
save_csv(dados)
```

Removing the try/except gives a file permission error if you have a file of the same name already open. You have to close any file you are trying to write (on windows at least).

Per Abdou's comment, if you (or the program) don't have write access to the directory then that would cause a permission error too.

Comment: Yes, i imported the time module.
I was running the script on "Notepad++". Using the IDLE (Python 3.6 32-bit) it worked. 
Thank you.

Comment: Please feel free to edit your answer with the comments I provided. The issue is a permission error resulting from the fact that Notepad (without being opened as Administrator) does not have access to some directories and therefore anything run inside it wouldn't be able to write to those directories.